# How to convert function to kernel?

Tags: convolution

Imagine I have a signal function, several examples: [PSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) [Wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet). How can I transform its logic into a kernel? By kernel I mean matrix which is used in the convolution afterward.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to express convolution-with-function-$f$ into an operator expressed by a kernel?

Comment: @paulgarrett,  Something like that. I want to be able to use a function as a matrix for image convolution.